# Spring - allowing a user to view a page as another user

Tags: spring-security, usergroups

We have a website with 2 user groups: the admin group and the customer group. The groups have different restrictions set up hence the admin group sees one set of products and the customer groups sees another. We're using a custom server based on Tomcat 6.0.29. We're also using Spring Security.

Is it possible with Spring to allow the admin to see a page from the customer group's perspective without forcing a log out of the admin user? If so, is there a link available showing the spring code?

Thanks! :)
Krt_Malta

Comment: Can you show how you have configured customer and admin group permissions?

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer over here:

[Different user restrictions in same session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204080/different-user-restrictions-in-same-session)

The SwitchUserFilter in Spring Security allows switching of users without a logout :)