# Angularjs + spring boot security change principal programmatically

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I've a webapp angular with Spring Boot as server which implements Spring Security. In my scenario I need three roles **admin user**, **trusted user**, **user**.
If I'm **admin** I can have one or more **trusted** as *child* and I need to take control of web app with one of my child credentials. Idem If I'm **trusted** I can have one or more **user** and so.
There is any way to apply a sort of pattern to govern this scenario?

Comment: What exactly do you mean "you can have one or more trusted/user". What does it mean for one user to have another?

Comment: Like father and one or more children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you're looking for user impersonation. You can see here an article about it.

http://www.disasterarea.co.uk/blog/user-impersonation-with-spring-security/

or in this question

[Different user restrictions in same session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204080/different-user-restrictions-in-same-session)

Comment: I'm using oauth2 approach, there is any possible to use user impersonation with this?

Comment: I haven't used oauth yet. But I think it's possible.  You can ask another question abot oauth and user impersonation. And add the code you have to the question.